# selecting the correct battery

Tags: batteries, pcb, pcb-design

I am trying to design a circuit on a PCB whose supply voltage needs to be 3.3 V.  Currently I have two options:

1. Use three AA batteries of 1.5 V each to obtain 4.5 V, then use a converter/regulator to bring it down to 3.3 V
2. Use a 9 V battery & bring it down to 3.3 V

Which would be the better option, considering that I am making a PCB (not sure if the PCB matters)?

Cost is not a factor with respect to the above 2 options.
My current requirement is around 100mA.
What i have understood after reading about smps is that they can cause some interference, i am using a zigbee on the same PCB, so will the smps coil interfere with the zigbee?

Comment: It comes down to a bunch of factors you haven't told us, like current, size, expected battery life, and whether you want to avoid switch mode regulators.

Comment: Need to know the current draw to make an informed decision. Also be aware that different battery technologies put out different voltages. For example, rechargeable Ni-MH batteries are about 1.2-1.3 V. And consider that battery voltage declines over the life of the battery.

Comment: Is size a factor?  If not, use 4 AA batteries and regulate down to 3.3 V with an LDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it depends on a lot of things. Although you claim cost is not an issue, there are other important issues such as design simplicity, volume/weight and efficiency (dealing with issues of heat generation and battery durability.)

Either way, you will need a voltage regulator, and here you'll have to choose between linear or switching regulators. The former are easier to design with, but less efficient; the latter are harder to design with and more efficient. Here are some considerations for both cases.

### Switching regulators

If efficiency is paramount, even at considerable cost in terms of design simplicity, I would go with a switching regulator. Although, in fact, many manufacturers offer easy to use ICs, with integrated switches, and generally the datasheet will describe a design procedure, which essentially consists of selecting a suitable inductor and output capacitor. You could go with a step-down regulator like a buck converter, a step-up regulator like a boost converter, or for ultimate flexibility, a buck-boost converter.

When using a buck converter, I wouldn't recommend only 3 AA batteries, especially if they could be rechargeable ones, since the most common chemistry (NiMH) has a typical voltage of 1.2 V, and three of these are too close to 3.3 V. Do note that most buck converters need some headroom; i.e. they can't reliably convert, say, 3.4 V to 3.3 V. Even if they could, once voltage goes below 1.1 V/cell, there's nothing you can do. So I would recommend 4 AA batteries in this case. When using a buck converter, to a first-order approximation, it won't matter very much if your input voltage is 4.5 V, 6 V or 9 V -- the efficiency of conversion to 3.3 V would be similar either way.

A second choice is a boost converter. In that case, you'd need to use at most 2 batteries, and even then, at 3 V you're quite close to 3.3 V -- some converters wouldn't be too happy with that. If you're not drawing too much current, a single battery would be OK. However, in that case you should take a close look at what kind of current you'll be drawing, recalling that whatever current you draw at 3.3 V, you may be drawing three times as much (in reality more, since the boost converter is not 100% efficient) once the battery goes down to 1.1 V. When you factor the practical limits for current draw and the increasing internal resistance of the battery with discharge level, this may mean the battery life will be shortened significantly unless your current draw is below about 100 mA or so. If you're using rechargeables exclusively, 2 AA batteries coupled with a boost converter is a very good choice.

Finally, a buck-boost converter is a good choice in that you may go with 2 or 3 AA batteries, rechargeable or not, and you should be able to drain them until they're essentially empty. However, I think the choice of integrated converters in this case is less plentiful than for the case of buck and boost converters.

### Linear regulators

The main other choice are linear regulators. Given the low voltages involved, you should definitely go with a low dropout (LDO) regulator. 3 non-rechargeable AA batteries would work but you'd be unable to extract all the chemical energy from them, since even with an ultra-low-dropout regulator, once you reach 1.1 V/cell, you'd lose regulation. 3 rechargeable AA batteries would be quickly exhausted. My suggestion would be to go with 4 AA batteries in this case, or if space is an issue, 4 AAA batteries. With 4 AA batteries, whether they're rechargeable or not is not really an issue, so long as you're using a low dropout regulator.

What I definitely would suggest avoiding is the 9 V battery. Besides the heat generation issue (since you'd be dropping out nearly 2/3 of its voltage in the regulator), its capacity in mAh is about 1/2 that of an AAA and 1/4-1/5 of an AA. 4 AAAs battery should take up about the same space, and last twice as long, in addition to not generating as much heat.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the regulator you want to use.

If you choose a linear regulator, the lower the voltage, the better.

With DC-DC you have more choices. I’d choose one that can support 4-10V input.  Then you have your choice of battery, depending on size / weight vs. run time. DC-DC is also more efficient.